# Convolution Input/output Units

Tags: filters, convolution, physical-units

How come are the units of convolution for LTI system not consistent?

$$y(t)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$$

$y(t)$ unit is volt, whereas the RHS has volt.time unit!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

impulse responses, $h(t)$, of continuous-time systems (those with output that is the same species of animal of the input) have dimensions 1/time.

consider a wire which has impulse response

$$ h(t) = \delta(t) $$

the area of the $\delta(t)$ is equal to the dimensionless $1$.  the width of the nascent delta is in dimension of time, so the height must be in dimension of 1/time.

the impulse response for a simple RC low-pass filter is

$$ h(t) = \tfrac{1}{RC} e^{-^{\, t}/_{RC}} \ u(t) $$

the dimension of $h(t)$ is in 1/time because $RC$ is in units of time.

Comment: I have some doubts... In circuit theory we do represent an impulsive voltage source $x(t)=K \delta(t)$ with the units of volts (or Amperes for a current source)? don't we? correct me if I'm wrong. For example if you were to **physically measure** the (approximate) impulse response of a circuit through a wire, you would do this with a **voltmeter** ? So $h(t)$ you have provided would be voltage accross some output port of a circuit with units of Volts... ?

Comment: the height of $x(t)=K \cdot \delta(t)$ would be volts.  so $K$ would be volt-seconds.  what comes out is $K \cdot h(t)$.

Comment: yes now that makes a lot more sense (I've checked the library for a few circuit books and reached the same result, which I was almost typing! :-) )

Comment: that value of $K$ would depend on how wide your nascent delta is.  so if the input was a thin pulse that is 2 volts tall and 3 $\mu$s wide, the value of $K$ is 6 $\mu$V-s.

Comment: I've still doubts however about the book, this time :-) impulse response can also be measured as voltage-in current-out form? or vice versa? I'll check their units as well...

Comment: yes, i was assuming that the species of animal coming out is the same species going it.  that makes the transfer function dimensionless (a simple ratio of like-dimensioned physical quantities).  if it's voltage in and current out, then the transfer function is in units of conductance and the impulse response would be conductance/time.

Comment: like consider an inductor, $L$, where the applied voltage is the input and the measured current is the output.  then $$ h(t) = \tfrac1L u(t) $$ with $u(t)$ as the unit step function.  $\frac1L$ is in units of 1/Henry but is also in units of mho/sec.